# Missing project templates in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2

Does anyone know how I find Navigation-based iOS application project template to create a new project in Xcode 4.2 ? For some reason Apple removed this and many others formerly available.

Thanks for any comment..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I found that you can replicate a simple, navigation based template by creating a new **Master-Detail Application** project and then **unchecking** the **use Core  Data**.

This should create a basic, Navigation based template which you can then use when going through books.

Hope this helps.

-Flea

Answer (score 0):

I never could figure out why Apple removed these templates. Perhaps they were so enamoured of their xib-file editing tools they thought it was really unnecessary. For you really can just create a project using the single view template, and then adding the Navigation controller from the Storyboard editor (or Interface Builder). See [Navigation based application in Xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311267/navigation-based-application-in-xcode-4-2) and its duplicate for more details.

One advantage to using this method instead of "Master-Detail" is that the names match what you expect from Xcode4 better this way.