# Navigation based application in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.2 creating navigation based application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869594/xcode-4-2-creating-navigation-based-application)

I am using Xcode 4.2, in earlier version of Xcode apple have provided template for navigation based application, but in Xcode 4.2 there is nothing called NavigationController.

How can we create navigation based application in Xcode 4.2

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone, you can use a master-detail view controller, or a simple view controller and edit the storyboard